# openpyxl - While loop runs infinitely although a similar logic in IF condition runs fine. Don't know where the problem is

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a column that has multiple values for student marks with gaps in between. I need to pick the last value before a blank cell in the column.

I'm doing the below where I'm check for values until the next cell in None and trying to save the value. But somehow my while loop runs without stopping although the counter is incremented correctly. If i'm doing a similar logic using IF, it print every next value correctly as expected.

```
for cell in row:
    if cell.value == "TEST level":
        print("Marks:")
        row_num=1
        while ("{1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(row=row_num, column=0).value)) is not None:
            print("Inside While loop")
            last_marks = "{1}".format(cell.value, cell.offset(row=row_num, column=0).value)
            row_num=row_num+1
        print(last_marks)
```

I'm unable to find where  the logic is going wrong. Can someone please point out my mistake and put me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Why do have a while loop within your other loops? Please simplify the question for one column in one worksheet.

Comment: I simplified the code now. Can you please find where my while loop is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code is now incomplete but you are continually resetting your row counter to 1 and your while condition is always true. It makes more sense to break the code into separate parts: first, find the relevant cell; second, do what you want to do with the rest of the cells in that column. It's still not clear from the code where you're searching.

```
for row in ws:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "TEST level":
             break

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=cell.row+1, min_col=cell.column, max_col=cell.column):
    cell = row[0]
    print("Last marks {0} {1}".format(cell.coordinate, cell.value))
```

This seems to match your code but not necessarily the logic in your question.